# How fill a matrix with 1 and 0 when there is association

Tags: r, matrix, fill

I´ve been trying to make a matrix from a data frame in R, without succes. I have the next data frame

```
Order        Object      idrA   idoA
8001505892  CHR56029398AB   1   1
8001506013  CHR56029398AB   1   2
8001507782  CHR56029398AB   1   3
8001508088  CHR56029398AB   1   4
8001508788  CHR56029398AB   1   5
8001509281  CHR56029398AB   1   6
8001509322  CHR56029398AB   1   7
8001509373  CHR56029398AB   1   8
8001505342  MMRMD343563     2   9
8001506699  MMRMD343563     2   10
8001507102  MMRMD343563     2   11
8001507193  MMRMD343563     2   12
8001508554  MMRMD343563     2   13
8001508654  MMRMD343563     2   14
8001509151  MMRMD343563     2   15
8001509707  MMRMD343563     2   16
8001509712  MMRMD343563     2   17
8001509977  MMRMD343563     2   18
8001510279  MMRMD343563     2   19
8001505342  MMRMD343565     3   9
8001507112  MMRMD343565     3   20
8001507193  MMRMD343565     3   12
8001508554  MMRMD343565     3   13
8001508654  MMRMD343565     3   14
8001509151  MMRMD343565     3   15
8001509707  MMRMD343565     3   16
8001509712  MMRMD343565     3   17
8001509977  MMRMD343565     3   18
8001510279  MMRMD343565     3   19
8001505920  MMRMN146319     4   21
8001506733  MMRMN146319     4   22
8001506929  MMRMN146319     4   23
8001507112  MMRMN146319     4   20
8001507196  MMRMN146319     4   24
8001510302  MMRMN146319     4   25
8001517272  MMRMN146319     4   26
8001506186  MMRMN146320     5   27
8001506733  MMRMN146320     5   22
8001506929  MMRMN146320     5   23
8001507112  MMRMN146320     5   20
8001508638  MMRMN146320     5   28
8001509526  MMRMN146320     5   29
8001505452  SSR664050011    6   30
8001508551  SSR664050011    6   31
8001509229  SSR664050011    6   32
8001510174  SSR664050011    6   33
```

Where `idr` are the Id for each object and `ido` is the Id for each purchase order. So I want to make a matriz with  the number of row = N° orders and N° columns= N°object, and fill it with a vector with 1s and 0s, with a 1 when in each order was purchased some of the bjects and 0 if it wasn´t.

Example: the order with `ido=20` must have a vector like this `(0,0,1,1,1,0)`.

I hope I could explain clearly, thanks!

Comment: Please revert your edit.  The original contained the data.  Your edits has removed context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` to create a cross table:

Recreate your data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                  Order        Object      idrA   idoA
                  8001505892  CHR56029398AB   1   1
                  ....
                  8001506013  CHR56029398AB   1   2
                  8001507782  CHR56029398AB   1   3
                  8001509229  SSR664050011    6   32
                  8001510174  SSR664050011    6   33")
```

Create the cross table:

```
xtabs(Order ~ idoA + idrA, dat) != 0

    idrA
idoA     1     2     3     4     5     6
  1   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  2   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ....
  20 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  ....
  32 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  33 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

To coerce the logical values to numeric values, you can use `apply()` and `as.numeric`, but then you have some work left to replace the row names:

```
 apply(xtabs(Order ~ idoA + idrA, dat) != 0, 2, as.numeric)
```

Or, you can use a little trick by adding 0 to the values.  This coerces the logical values to numeric:

```
 (xtabs(Order ~ idoA + idrA, dat) != 0) + 0

    idrA
idoA 1 2 3 4 5 6
  1  1 0 0 0 0 0
  2  1 0 0 0 0 0
  3  1 0 0 0 0 0
....
```

Comment: could I change the FALSE by 0s and TRUES by 1s?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `acast` from `reshape2`

```
 library(reshape2)
 res1 <- (acast(dat, idoA~idrA, value.var='Order', fill=0)!=0)+0

 head(res1)
#  1 2 3 4 5 6
#1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#2 1 0 0 0 0 0
#3 1 0 0 0 0 0
#4 1 0 0 0 0 0
#5 1 0 0 0 0 0
#6 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 dat %>% 
     select(-Object) %>% 
     spread(idrA, Order, fill=0) %>%
     mutate_each(funs((!!.)+0), select=-idoA) %>%
     head()
 #idoA 1 2 3 4 5 6
#1    1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#2    2 1 0 0 0 0 0
#3    3 1 0 0 0 0 0
#4    4 1 0 0 0 0 0
#5    5 1 0 0 0 0 0
#6    6 1 0 0 0 0 0
```